# How problematic is the exposure of Firebase configuration data when using web push?

Tags: javascript, firebase, service-worker, web-push

When implementing Web Push Notifications (using a Service Worker) via Firebase in a website, it seems all the Firebase configuration data must be present in JavaScript files that can be accessed and read by anyone accessing the website.

`apiKey, vapidKey, messagingSenderId, appId, etc.`

I am wondering if I'm suffering from a fundamental misunderstanding here, or if this just the way it is.

I followed the instructions in the official Firebase documentation and my code looks basically the same as the examples I can find.

Right before doing the

```
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);
```

I need to have the firebaseConfig defined literally in the JavaScript file – for anyone to read.

And when doing the

```
firebase_getToken(messaging, ...)
```

the vapidKey also needs to be present in the code.

As it all is happening on the client side (in the browser - either page or service worker), I cannot see a way around it.

Just wondering about the security implications of it.

Anyone shining a light on that for me would by highly appreciated!

Regards
J.